# passing json object data to a php file

Tags: php, json, object

I have very little coding experience, (Bigtimenoob) but have recently purchased some code which I need to edit.

I wish to send the results to a PHP file so I can record. I want to send the results to `wheelresults.php` which I have set as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
   <?php
       $file = fopen("wheeldata.txt","a");
       fclose($file);
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

But how do I get the information from the object to this file?

```
// Usage
// load your JSON (you could jQuery if you prefer)
function loadJSON(callback)
{
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', './wheel_data.json', true); 
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
            //Call the anonymous function (callback) passing in the response
            callback(xobj.responseText);
        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}

//your own function to capture the spin results
function myResult(e)
{
    //e is the result object
    console.log('Spin Count: ' + e.spinCount + ' - ' + 'Win: ' + e.win + ' - ' + 'Message: ' +  e.msg);
    // if you have defined a userData object...
    if(e.userData){
        console.log('User defined score: ' + e.userData.score)
    }
    /*  if(e.spinCount == 3){
    show the game progress when the spinCount is 3
    console.log(e.target.getGameProgress());
    restart it if you like
    e.target.restart();
    }*/
}

//your own function to capture any errors
function myError(e)
{
    //e is error object
    console.log('Spin Count: ' + e.spinCount + ' - ' + 'Message: ' +  e.msg);
}

function myGameEnd(e)
{
    //e is gameResultsArray
    console.log(e);
    //reset the wheel at the end of the game after 5 seconds
    /*  TweenMax.delayedCall(1, function(){
    Spin2WinWheel.reset();
    })*/
}

function init()
{
    loadJSON(function(response) {
        // Parse JSON string to an object
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
        //if you want to spin it using your own button, then create a reference and pass it in as spinTrigger
        var mySpinBtn = document.querySelector('.spinBtn');
        //create a new instance of Spin2Win Wheel and pass in the vars object
        var myWheel = new Spin2WinWheel();
        //WITH your own button
        myWheel.init({data:jsonData, onResult:myResult, onGameEnd:myGameEnd, onError:myError, spinTrigger:mySpinBtn});
        //WITHOUT your own button
        //myWheel.init({data:jsonData, onResult:myResult, onGameEnd:myGameEnd, onError:myError});
    });
}
//And finally call it
init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, yes, Chris Gannon's classic [Spin2WinWheel](https://codecanyon.net/item/spin2win-wheel-spin-it-2-win-it/16337656)!

In the `myGameEnd` function, you want to send `e` to your `wheelresults.php`.

This can be done by making an AJAX call:

```js
function myGameEnd(e)
{
    //e is gameResultsArray
    console.log(e);
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', '/wheelresults.php', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8');
    request.send("result=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(e)));
}
```

Please note that your current PHP code doesn't actually *write* anything to the`wheeldata.txt` file.

You might want to use [`file_put_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for that.

```php
   <?php
        file_put_contents(
            "wheeldata.txt",
            filter_var($_POST['result'], FILTER_VALIDATE_STRING),
            FILE_APPEND
        );
    ?>
```